# projective homogeneous $G$-variety is equivariantly isomorphic to a partial flag variety $G/P$ where $P$ is projective variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, homogeneous-spaces

I am looking for a proof(or refference) for this fact

A projective homogeneous $G$-variety is equivariantly isomorphic to a partial flag variety $G/P$ where $P$ is parabolic subgroup.

Comment: You mean where $P$ is a parabolic subgroup?

Comment: Yes, It was i edited it.

Comment: Assuming that $G$ is a complex reductive Lie group, this is pretty much the definition of what a parabolic subgroup is: It is an algebraic subgroup of $G$ such that $G/P$ is projective. Then there is a separate theory classifying such subgroups in terms of subsets of the set of positive roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is a projective and homogeneous $G$-variety, then $X=G.x$ for any $x\in X$, in particular $X=G/G_x$. Since $X$ is projective, $G_x$ is parabolic, this is often the *definition* of being parabolic. See 28.1.3 and 28.1.4 in the Book by Tauvel and Yu, *Lie Algebras and Algebraic Groups* - the first of these two items also explains why being parabolic is equivalent to fixing a partial flag.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your comment was very helpful